# ClassNotFoundException after increment version apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

Please help with solving the problem. After upgrading the apache camel version from 2.24.3 to 3.20.6, the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/support/ServiceSupport
```

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you need to add `camel-support` dependency.
See https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_migrating_custom_components

In general, take time to read the migration guides https://camel.apache.org/manual/migration-and-upgrade.html